# Excel Formula (If last 8 characters of cell are greater than....)

Tags: c#, excel, formula

I need to find a formula for Excel (eventually will be a string in C#) that looks at the last 8 characters in a cell (last 8 of 17) and displays a result if those 8 numbers are greater than eg 11111111.

So if A1 contains XXXXXXXXX11111112 B1 would show the contents of A1,
If A1 contains XXXXXXXXX11100009 B1 would show nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IF(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,8))>11111111,A1,"")
```

this?

```
=IF(AND(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,8))>11111111,VALUE(RIGHT(A1,8))<22222222),A1,"")
```

would be a possible solution for your second question

Comment: One further question, would it be possible to do the same thing but if it is between two values  eg 11111111-22222222

Comment: That is excellent, would you know if there is a way that letters could be considered as numbers with a higher value than 9? eg if A1111111 appeared it would read it as greater than 91111111 ?

Comment: In fact, Excel can do this per se without any need for additional formulas. It will compare string values, giving numbers a lower value than a letter. Just type`="A11111111">"911111111"` in a cell and you will see it works. If you want to apply this to our formula above you basically only need to remove the VALUE() function (as it attempts to convert text into numbers)